# How to get current variant value in Flutter widget test

Tags: flutter, widget-test-flutter

Let's imagine I have an enum to represent some colors;

```dart
enum MyColor { blue, red, green }
```

Not to duplicate test cases I can write a `TestVariant` like below;

```dart
class ColorVariant extends TestVariant<MyColor> {
  @override
  String describeValue(MyColor value) {
    return value.toString();
  }

  @override
  Future<Object?> setUp(MyColor value) {
    // Do setup here
    return Future.value(null);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> tearDown(MyColor value, covariant Object? memento) {
    // Do teardown here
    return Future.value();
  }

  @override
  Iterable<MyColor> get values => MyColor.values;
}
```

Finally below a corresponding testWidget function;

```dart
testWidgets(
  'Should reflect Color',
  (tester) async {
    // Test block here..
  },
  variant: ColorVariant(),
);
```

So the actual question is, how to get the related *MyColor* in test block?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

1. Add property `currentValue` to `ColorVariant` class and set it on `setUp`.
2. Create the instance of it and access it in the `testWidgets` body.

#### Full Code

```dart
enum MyColor { blue, red, green }

final variant = ColorVariant()

class ColorVariant extends TestVariant<MyColor> {
  /// Returns the value currently under test.
  MyColor? get currentValue => _currentValue;
  MyColor? _currentValue;

  @override
  String describeValue(MyColor value) {
    return value.toString();
  }

  @override
  Future<MyColor> setUp(MyColor value) async => _currentValue = value;

  @override
  Future<void> tearDown(MyColor value, covariant Object? memento) {
    // Do teardown here
    return Future.value();
  }

  @override
  Iterable<MyColor> get values => MyColor.values;
}

testWidgets(
  'Should reflect Color',
  (tester) async {
     // access via currentValue
    final current = variants.currentValue!.name;

  },
  variant: ColorVariant(),
);
```

#### Recommended

Or if you do not have any additional configuration like `setUp` or `tearDown`, you can just use `ValueVariant`.

```dart
enum MyColor { blue, red, green }

final variants = ValueVariant({...MyColor.values});
```